# Dynamically adding predicate in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

In Ado.NET world, I could have code like following

```
Void SomeMethod(bool flag)
{
String Query = “ SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryID  = 125”;
If ( flag == true )
  Query += “ AND Price > 25”
....
}
```

In the Linq world, can I add these additional filters  dynamically ?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (someFlag)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Price > 25);
```

Comment: so the query will already containing thr results for CateogryID meaning in that case I will be hitting database twice?

Comment: no it will not hit the database until you actually fetch results

Comment: No, query expressions are lazy.  The query won't be executed until you force it to produce an output (i.e. by calling `ToList()`).

Answer (score 7):

```
var query = context.Products.Where( p => p.CategoryID == 125 );
if ( flag )
   query = query.Where( p => p.Price > 25 );
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that it is still possible to initialize `query` with a query expression such as `var query = from p in Products where p.CategoryID == 125 select p;` and still apply the `Price`-filter dynamically.

Comment: And what would be the difference?

Comment: There wouldn't be any difference, except that the first line of code would look like @MagnusHoff 's example.

Answer (score 3):

You can cheat and use the flag as part of the query.

```
var query = from p in Products
            where p.CategoryID == 125
                && (!flag || p.Price > 25)
            select p
            ;
```

If you're *passing in* the extra criteria, you can just apply them to the enumerable and get a new enumerable, as SLaks and Wiktor Zychla mentioned.  The query won't be resolved until you call `ToList`:

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(params Func<Product, bool>[] criteria)
{
    var query = Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == 125);
    foreach(criterion in criteria)
    {
        query = query.Where(criterion);
    }
    return query;
}

// ...

var notFiltered = someObject.GetProducts().ToList();
var filtered = someObject
    .GetProducts(
        p => p.Price > 25,
        p => p.AverageReviewScore > 4
        )
    .ToList();
```

Note that if you do this with Linq to Entities instead of Linq to Objects this might not work as well, or you'll at least have to return `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`.  Haven't tried it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = from p in context.Products 
           where (flag == false && p.CategoryID == 125)
                 || (flag == true && p.CategoryID == 125 && p.Price > 25)
           select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void GetData(bool flag)
    {
        var query = from p in db.products
                    where p.CategoryId == 125
                    select p;

            if(flag)
        query = query.Where(o => o.Price > 25);
    }
```